Weather, climate, tides and meteorology on the internal surface of a sphere
In the world I'm building I have a something similar to a Dyson Sphere. This is a fantasy world, not hard sci-fi. However, to make the world immersive I want to make sure the physical environment is internally consistent.
This involves figuring out tides, climate and general meteorology.
Context:

The world is approximately 1.5x the radius of Earth (9000km, works out about 2.25x the surface area)
The surface is mostly ocean.
assume a "negative gravity", for lack of a better term, that attracts towards the spheres surface / pushes away from the central star.
"null zones" are a thing. They are areas of the surface that has super positive enthalpy, removing thermal energy from their surrounds.
Assume an earth like layered atmosphere from the surface with a troposphere, stratosphere, mesosphere... etc. The center of the world (the star) would be vacuum.

Question:
How would the concave nature of the surface affect the large scale movement of water, tides etc and, by extension, the atmosphere?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

We accept only 1 question per post. And that question must have a manageable scope, not requiring to write a whole book to be answered.

@Community edited to only pose one question.

Its always sunny in the Dyson sphere
If your surface is evenly heated, the energy gradient will not help move your oceans and air around. This is a problem you already mitigated with your "null zones". I am touching on it because if your null zones are artificial, then you can put them anywhere. The energy differentials will move your currents and weather around by creating high and low pressure systems like on earth.
Coriolis Effect
Is your sphere spinning? If so, the currents and jets will be stronger around your equator. The centrifugal/centripetal perceived forces will behave exactly like on earth since you have some sort of negative gravity keeping everything on the inner surface. The concave nature of your surface should be negligible.
Get a super moon
Does your star system have a Jupiter sized planet? Jupiter is large enough that we can say the sun and Jupiter orbit each other. In fact, the center of rotation of their system is outside the sun. If you have a large planet (or planets) orbiting your star, they could do interesting things to your currents and tides.

One detail is that the Coriolis Effect would be backwards; the rotation would appear opposite looking in from the surface of the planet instead of looking out towards space. Irrelevant most of the time, but might surprise a visitor from a more normal planet, or screw up computers/algorithms used to predict weather that weren't programmed with this in mind.

All parts of a Dyson Shell, as opposed to the original Dyson Sphere which was what we now often call a Dyson Swarm, receive the same amount of insolation. thus to vary the temperature at all you need to alter the insulative qualities of the material that the shell is made of. The concavity of the surface is visible only on the stellar scale, it makes no difference to the movement of water and atmosphere around the environment; the surface of the shell is effectively flat over thousands of kilometers even around a very small star. A Dyson Shell does not spin so there is no Coriolis Force to deflect winds from a straight path between high and low pressure zones.
With all of that in mind the only forces affecting the weather then are the direct temperature gradients between areas of varying insulation. Areas of greater insulation retain solar heat, and so are home to permanent columns of rising hot air, thunder storms, and rain. Areas with less insulation are cold sinks, home to falling columns of cold, dry, air. This means that there will be large circulation cells similar to Earth's Hadley Cells but without any particular pattern apart from what the Dyson Shell creators built in at the point of inception.
Unless there is something, massive, other than the sun, in the system there will be no tides.
